# Defining whether the current system locale is RTL or LTR

Tags: c++, winapi, internationalization

We develop a Windows API app where there is a context menu with nested submenus. We localize the app in several languages, including Hebrew.
As keyboard support is a must for us, we need to know whether the submenu should be opened upon right arrow (LTR) or left arrow (RTL) keypress.
Our developer does use the `TrackPopupMenu()` function described [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002(v=vs.85).aspx), but he needs to know *when* to set the `TPM_LAYOUTRTL` flag.
So the question is: how to define whether the current system locale is LTR or RTL to handle the menus properly?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/22/10250164.aspx

Comment: Exactly, thank you! We have found this same solution a couple minutes ago :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm answering since we have found a solution (and a comment confirmed we are on the right way).
In order to define whether the current system locale is RTL or LTR, we should use [`GetLocaleInfoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318103.aspx) with [`LOCALE_IREADINGLAYOUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373806.aspx). MSDN says the following about it:

> Windows 7 and later: The reading layout for text. Possible values are defined in the following table.

Possible values actually are:

- `0` — left-to-right (as in English);
- `1` — right-to-left (as in Hebrew or Arabic);
- `2` — Either read vertically from top to bottom with columns going from right to left, or read in horizontal rows from left to right (as in Japanese);
- `3` — Read vertically from top to bottom with columns going from left to right (as in Mongolian).

Answer (score 1):

We use the following in-house code:

```
bool IsCurrentInputLanguageRTL ( void )
{
  bool ret=false;
auto layout = GetKeyboardLayout(GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL));

  auto lcid=MAKELCID(LOWORD(layout),SORT_DEFAULT);
  LOCALESIGNATURE localesig;

  // Windows XP and higher.
  // Unicode subset bit fields: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374090(v=vs.85).aspx
  // Bit 123: Windows 2000 and later - Layout progress, horizontal from right to left.
  if(GetLocaleInfoW(lcid,LOCALE_FONTSIGNATURE,(LPWSTR)&localesig,sizeof(localesig)/sizeof(WCHAR)) != 0)
    ret = (localesig.lsUsb[3] & 0x08000000)!=0;

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: True, the point for me was that the other option isn't available if your target is older than Windows 7