# How to get reading direction of keyboard layout

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm implementing a simple text editor using direct2d on Windows. I want to determine the reading direction to know where to place the cursor. I'm using `IDWriteTextLayout` which can tell whether a glyph is right to left or left to right through `HitTestTextPosition` method which returns `DWRITE_HIT_TEST_METRICS` containing `UINT32 bidiLevel` which determines the direction of that glyph. The problem is when the layout is empty (no text is entered yet) I want to place the cursor on right if the keyboard is set to a right to left language (like Arabic) and place it on the left if the keyboard is left to right (like English). I can get an `HKL` from `GetKeyboardLayout` and get the language id or retrieve the layout name with `GetKeyboardLayoutName` but I don't see a function to get the reading direction from any of these. The method I'm thinking of is to have a hardcoded list of language ids for right to left languages and check if the returned id in `HKL` is one of them, but I don't think this is the best way to do it because the list may be incomplete and Microsoft says that Windows 8 has `LOCALE_TRANSIENT_KEYBOARD1` and `LOCALE_TRANSIENT_KEYBOARD2` which I don't know how to get the direction of. Is there a ready to use function in the `winapi` to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GetLocaleInfoEx` with [LOCALE_IREADINGLAYOUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-ireadinglayout) as [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576930/defining-whether-the-current-system-locale-is-rtl-or-ltr) showed.
While you can use the `LayoutDirection` property of the preferred user display language in WinUI3/CppWinRT. See [Handling right-to-left (RTL) languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/adjust-layout-and-fonts--and-support-rtl#handling-right-to-left-rtl-languages).

Comment: I figured this days ago but forgot to post an answer. Glad to see you answering the question. Upvoted!